# General spelling rule: no double (repeated) consonant after another consonant?

Tags: spelling, consonants

Is it correct to tell ESL students that there aren't any words in English that have a double repeated consonant after another consonant?

For example:

- **Stt**rugle
- I**nff**ection
- di**spp**osal

Thanks!

Comment: [Hmm..](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hmm).

Comment: English spelling is irregular. It does not have patterns for uninflected words. However, for inflected words, [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/248082/106592) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

English spelling has patterns, but no perfectly reliable rules. Even very common patterns such as your example have exceptions, to the bane of all.

A double consonant following another consonant is possible when the double consonant crosses a morpheme boundary, as in words like *[dumbbell](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/dumbbell)* or *[jackknife](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/jackknife_1)*. This includes most of the obscure words or spellings claimed to feature triple consonants, like *goddessship* or *crosssection* (in practice, such words are generally hyphenated, *[goddess-ship](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/goddess-ship)*, *[cross-section](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cross-section)*).

Another set of exceptions would be various representations of sounds, like *[psst](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/psst)* or *[zzz](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/zzz)*. , though some might object to their classification as words.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you! Would it be a safe bet to say, rather, " with a few exceptions"? (or are there lots?)

Comment: Yes, I think it's safe to say it's very uncommon for a double consonant to follow another consonant— besides the two I gave, the only other exception I could think of was *knickknack*.